# Loading large geoJson object as layer on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, geojson

i have geoJson file over 40 MB i want to load this file on google map as i required each feature to have featureClickListener.
i am getting chunks of geoJson file from server which i am reading and storing it in file at cache directory then after getting all chunks navigating to google activity where am reading this and storing all data in single geoJson object and adding this object as geoJson layer on map.

now the problem is, when i am trying to add the object as geojson layer to map through main thread,  due to large size main thread is blocked and i am getting application not responding as i am loading this object throught the main thread.

i am refering the googles map utility classes.

please help or let me know if there is alternate solution to this.

**Reading file and storing in jsoObject**

```
private fun getGeoJsonObjectAndLoadOnMap() {

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            geoJsonObject = readJsonObjectFromFile() // reading file and returning as JsonObject

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                geoJsonObject?.let { loadGeoJsonObject(it) } // updating feature through main thread causing the ANR 
            }

        }
    }
```

**Loading jsonObject on map**

```
private fun loadGeoJsonObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) {

        val markerManager = MarkerManager(mMap)
        val groundOverlayManager = GroundOverlayManager(mMap)
        val polygonManager = PolygonManager(mMap)
        val polylineManager = PolylineManager(mMap)

        // GeoJSON polygon
        val geoJsonPolygonLayer = GeoJsonLayer(
            mMap,
            jsonObject,
            markerManager,
            polygonManager,
            polylineManager,
            groundOverlayManager
        )
        val geoJsonPolygonStyle = GeoJsonPolygonStyle()
        geoJsonPolygonStyle.strokeWidth = 2.5f
        for (f in geoJsonPolygonLayer.features) {
            f.polygonStyle = geoJsonPolygonStyle
        }

        geoJsonPolygonLayer.addLayerToMap()

        geoJsonPolygonLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener(GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener { feature: Feature ->
            Toast.makeText(
                this@CacheGeoJsonLoadingActivity,
                "GeoJSON polygon clicked: " + feature.id,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

        } as GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener)
    }
```

Comment: Consider using Deck.gl for displaying such large GeoJSON objects. More info in [my handbook](https://gmapsbook.com/learn-google-maps/webgl-deckgl-carto-81903d1f69284181b405c005b0976eb7).